# "Sticky" side bar - setting bottom margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a "sticky" sidebar contact form with jQuery, which turns to fixed-positioned div when page is scrolled down. My problem is that it overlaps the footer when scrolled down all the way. Is there a way where I could set it not to scroll down any further once its bottom margin starts hitting the footer? I'm not sure how I would detect that event, if at all possible, because it's a responsive site and footer's height varies.

CSS:

```
.sticky {
  margin-top: 38px;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){ // document ready

  if (!!jQuery('.sticky').offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists

    var stickyTop = jQuery('.sticky').offset().top; // returns number

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event

      var windowTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

      if (stickyTop < windowTop){
        jQuery('.sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0 });
      }
      else {
        jQuery('.sticky').css('position','static');
      }

    });

  }
```

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: I think you're editing the page as it changes every time I look at it!  Maybe setup a JSFiddle or a CodePen or another location where you wont edit it!

Comment: sorry, i have not edited anything but I did find a full solution already that has a "stopper" https://github.com/AndrewHenderson/jSticky